# How to set variable = a value from a function result inside async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Inside a function, I would like to set the value of a variable (foldersInDir) to the results of getting the contents of a directory using fs.readdir();

I thought using await would force the console.log line to wait for a response, but it's not.

How can I set foldersInDir = the return value?

```
/*Begin function*/
const listContents = async (myPath) => {

    var fs = require('fs');

    let foldersInDir = await fs.readdir(myPath, function(err, items) {
        console.log(items); //works
        return  items;
    });

    console.log(foldersInDir); //does not work, undefined

}
```

Comment: If you want to use `await`, don't pass a callback function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @pointy I removed await and it still is undefined.

Comment: Please check link : https://dev.to/damcosset/asynchronous-code-with-asyncawait-7cd.
its help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `readdir` to a promise, e.g.:

```
const foldersPromised = (path) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    fs.readdir(path, (err, items) =>
      err !== undefined ? reject(err) : resolve(items)
    )
  );
try {
  let foldersInDir = await foldersPromised(myPath);
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: Just use [`fsPromises.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options)

Comment: Good point, turns out it's already there starting with v10. Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @bredikhin - I get null when I try to console out foldersInDir

Comment: @Tf11 Hmm, maybe a scope issue? As per the listing `foldersInDir` will only exist within the `try` block.

Comment: @FelixKling unfortunately we are running v8  on prod now.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fs = require('fs');

const test = () => {
        let folders = fs.readdirSync('.');
        return folders;
}

console.log(test());
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: sorry, need to promisify() the function

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util') // available in node v8 onwards
const readdir = promisify(fs.readdir)

async function listContents() {
  try {                                         // wrap in try-catch in lieu of .then().catch() syntax
    const foldersInDir = await readdir(myPath)  // call promised function
    console.log('OK, folders:', foldersInDir)   // success
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('FAIL reading dir:', e)         // fail
  }  
}

listContents('path/to/folder') // run test
```

Comment: So, `fs.readdir` returns a promise when no callback is passed? Can you point to some documentation where this is described?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the `promisify` function provided by Node.js to fix the problem. This function will convert a callback-based function to a promise-based function, which can then be used using the `await` keyword.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const {
  promisify
} = require('util');

const readdirAsync = promisify(fs.readdir);

/*Begin function*/
const listContents = async(myPath) => {
  let foldersInDir = await readdirAsync(myPath);

  console.log(foldersInDir);
}
```

Comment: [Node directly provides promise APIs for fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readdir_path_options)

Comment: @FelixKling I agree that it’s an alternative, but to be fair, it’s an experimental API added in the latest version of Node.js. For now, promisify seems to be more stable.